# Android - Keeping SearchView opened in Fragment ViewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

So.. I have a `Fragment` containing `ViewPager` with two more `Fragments` in it which serves as search tabs. That means 3 different Java classes, 1 for container, the 2 are for the contents.

The behavior I wanted was : When user presses the search button, types something, and submit the search in the base `Activity`, the app overrides `onQueryTextSubmit` to start the pager `Fragment` and getting the query there to directly search in the first `Fragment` in the pager. When user swipe to the next `Fragment`, the SearchView persists, along with its query and also perform search on the second `Fragment` using said query.

The behavior I am getting is.. When user swipes to the next `Fragment`, the searchmenu collapses and the keyword is gone..

This is how I code the `SearchVenu` in the `Activity`

```
@Override
public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
    searchFragment = new SearchFragment();
    Bundle searchBundle = new Bundle();
    keyword = searchView.getQuery().toString();
    searchBundle.putString("searchQuery", keyword);
    searchFragment.setArguments(searchBundle);
    backstackCount = manager.getBackStackEntryCount();
        if (backstackCount >= 2) {
            manager.executePendingTransactions();
            if (manager.getBackStackEntryAt(backstackCount - 1).getName().equals("searchTag")) {

            } else {
                replaceFragment(searchFragment, searchTag);
            }
        } else {
            replaceFragment(searchFragment, searchTag);
        }
return false;
```

The adapter :

```
mAdapter = new MyPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager(), bundle);

...

private class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    private Bundle fragmentBundle;

    public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, Bundle data) {
        super(fm);
        fragmentBundle = data;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int pos) {
        /*Fragment f = new Fragment();
        f.setArguments(this.fragmentBundle);
        return f;*/

        switch(pos) {
            case 0: return SearchFriendFragment.newInstance(fragmentBundle);
            case 1: return SearchShopFragment.newInstance(fragmentBundle);
            default: return SearchFriendFragment.newInstance(fragmentBundle);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return CONTENT[position % CONTENT.length];
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        //return 3;
        return CONTENT.length;
    }
}
```

This is how I initialize the search in one of the `Fragments`

```
@Override
public void onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    menu.clear();
    super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    getActivity().getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_search, menu);
    searchViewBtn = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search);
    searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchViewBtn);
```

I am well aware by doing `menu.clear()` will keep refreshing the menu on switching `Fragment`.. But I don't know what to do to get the correct behavior..

Update menu_search.xml

```
    <item
    android:id="@+id/menu_search"
    android:orderInCategory="200"
    android:title="Search"
    android:icon="@drawable/iconcariheader"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"></item>
```

Comment: use setHasOptionMenu(true) in your fragment oncreateview in which fragment you want to show searchBar

Comment: @Ankur1994a Yes I did, the `SearchView` is visible but it's collapsed and no query there..

Comment: can you show your searchmenu code?

Comment: You mean the SearchMenu in xml?? Or the one in each Fragment??

Comment: app:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"

replace this line and use onOptionsItemSelected  for get action on click of searchView.

Comment: Ohh wouldn't that be on every `onClick` on the `SearchView`? What I wanted is after `onQueryTextSubmit`.. Which means user enter the query, then goes to the other page and a search using the query will be performed there..

Comment: its not do search on click. it expand your searchbar where you can give your query.

Answer (score 0):

use my suggestion like this

```
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
 {
   switch(item.getItemId())
   {
    case R.id.menu_search:
    searchView = (SearchView) item.getActionView();
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener
        (new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() 
           {
                @Override
                public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                    // call your search function
                     return true;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                    // call your search function
                      return true;
                }
            });
          break;
     }
     return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
   }
```

Hope this will help and let me know for further.